# Sorting a matrix by column and by row

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have to build a function that sorts a matrix by rows and then by colums or the other way around, preserving the values inside the matrix.
The matrix is a huge matrix so the algorithm that I use has to be a nlogn algorithm.

I have a structure as follows:

```
typedef struct{
unsigned int line, column;
float value;}Matrix;

Matrix matrix[size_of_matrix*size_of_matrix];
static int numb_of_matrix; /*Whenever I ask the user to insert values to the matrix, I increase this number to insert the structure inside my vector matrix*/
```

I also store the maximun and minimun index of rows and columns that are filled by the user, and the indexs inbetween those boundaries are set as 0, so I create a matrix of size_of_matrix*size_of_matrix full of 0's and then I insert my values there while storing the highest and lowest index of row and column filled by the user.

Given that, I need to sort my matrix by sorting in the increasing order of rows and then by the increasing order of columns, or the other way around.
The way that I have to know which way it is that I have to sort the matrix is to ask the user to input C if I need to sort the matrix by columns first of nothing if I need to sort the matrix by rows first.

So if I have introduced to the matrix the following:

```
[0,3]=1.2
[3,0]=2.1
[4,5]=2.2
[2,5]=3.2
[3,5]=4.2
```

and then I sort it by lines first, it should become

```
[0,3]=1.2
[2,5]=3.2
[3,0]=2.1
[3,5]=4.2
[4,5]=2.2
```

This problem would be quick to solve if the matrix was small enough, but my matrix will have near 1 million values, so I can't use the likes of bubble sort or any other n^2 sorting algorithm.

Comment: Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms you have lots of sorting algorithms listed together with complexity.

Comment: Is "the user" a human typing input? Or another piece of a program?

Comment: Are all input given at the same time? Or do you need to accept new input and do a sort at any time?

Comment: @4386427 I can both read from a file, or a human input. 
I have a function that reads the input and stores it as the program runs. So the input, if given by a human, is given whenever he wants, and I have to the sort the matrix if the user wants as well.

Comment: Why don't you just place the elements directly at the correct position in the matrix?

Comment: I have a feeling that you have misunderstood this assignment. This looks like a technique used for a sparse matrix, i.e. a matrix where there are few non-zero elements.

Comment: @4386427 educational purposes. It's a school project and In which I have to develop an "app" that does multiple things. And yes, this is an assignment that deals with sparse matrix

Comment: For a sparse matrix there are few non-zero elements so the whole idea is to save memory by only storing the non-zero elements. So you don't need a complete matrix filled with zeros to start with. Further, since there are only few non-zero elements, it doesn't matter that the whole matrix is huge. The sorting is only to be done on the few no-zero elements. So `qsort` should be fine

Comment: @4386427 but I have functions in which I have to print the lines or columns from the min to the max index that were given to me. So what do I do in that case? Do i fill the blank with zeros? If so, how ?
Would qsort sort me the values given by line and then by column without losing the value of the position?

For example,
[4,4]=2
[3,2]=4
[3,5]=5

how would qsort put it in this order
[3,2]=4
[3,5]=5
[4,4]=2

??

Comment: Yes. If you an element in (0, 0) = 5.2 and the next element is (0, 123) = 6.7 and you are to print row 0, then you print 5.2 and then 0 122 times and then print 6.7 and so on. That's part of the idea here. If (0, 1) isn't present in your list, you know it's value is zero. A sparse 1000x1000 matrix may for instance only hold 3-4000 no-zero elements that you need to store. So you save a lot of memory but get more complicated operation.

Comment: Hmm but if I put the values in order from the input, I can't print in the the order the input was given to me.

So what I mean by that is, if the user doesn't want to sort the matrix, it needs to print the matrix in the order it was given by him. If he then decides to sort it, it then only prints the sorted matrix.

Btw, if it needs to sort by lines first, all the user need to do is to call the sorting function. If it needs to sort by columns first, the user needs to give me a the word column when he calls the function. How would I check for both conditions ?

Comment: Let us say that the sparse matrix is 1000x1000. When you read it from file/user, you only get 100 elements. You store these element in a array. When the user ask you to sort (by row or by column), you do the sorting **only** on those 100 elements in the array. When printing it is your job to print out a zero for those elements in the huge matrix that isn't present in your small array.

Comment: @4386427 Ok thanks. Btw, I have to read multiple options with a switch(option) from the stdin.  The options are chars. If in my function add I can read  the 3 numbers and then set the buffer to zero, but then if I press p to print my matrix, it returns my default option and does not read the input. What do I do?

Comment: If you are using `scanf("%c", &some_char)` make sure to have a space beteen `"` and `%c`. Like `scanf(" %c", &some_char)`

Comment: @4386427
how am I suppose to fill in the zeros and print an entire line between my most left column and most right colum?

like, for line 3 and for the following inputs
    `(3,0) = 3
    (3,4)=9
....
print_line(3)-> 0 0 0 0 9`

Comment: @4386427

Currently, what I am doing is

`void print_line(){
unsigned int ii,userLine, j;
scanf("%u", &userLine);
if((userLine<workingMatrix.minLine) || (userLine>workingMatrix.maxLine)){
printf("empty line\n");
}
else{
for(ii=0;ii<matrixcount;ii++){
if(auxMatrix[ii].line!=userLine){
printf("empty line\n");break;
}
else{
        for(j=workingMatrix.minCol;j<=workingMatrix.maxCol;j++){
if(auxMatrix[ii].line==userLine){
printf("%.3f \n",auxMatrix[ii].value);
}
else if(auxMatrix[ii].line!=userLine){
printf("%.3f \n",(float)workingMatrix.zero);}}}}}
printf("\n");}`

Comment: @4386427 it prints me 0 0 0 0 9 9 9 in the example I gave you

Comment: as you state, your loosing option values.  However, you have not posted a [mcve] so we have no real idea as to what the source of your problem is.  So make is simple on your self and us by posting a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The format that you are saving the matrix is called triplet format. Sorting them in row or column order means saving them in compressed sparse column (CSC) or compressed sparse row (CSR) format. 
Most sparse libraries implemented them efficiently. Converting CSC to CSR or vice versa is just a matrix transpose. If you are looking for a small efficient code, you can look at "cs_transpose" function in SuiteSparse/CSparse. 
For converting triplet to any compressed form it is just like that. counting number of elements in each row/column and then putting them in the right place in order (Like a bucket sort). The algorithm would bo O(n), but the elements within a row/column are not sorted. 
A simple solution would be transposing them. Transposing twice is actually used  in practice!